# Scrape XML files into RSS feed as input for IFTTT

Tags: python, wordpress, rss, yql, yahoo-pipes

I've got a set of XML files with article content (title, subtitle, content). I've got a Yahoo Pipe that finds the article XML for a specific date and turns it into an RSS feed. This feed is read by IFTTT to publish the article for today on my Wordpress blog.

Now Yahoo Pipes is going down in September, and I'm in trouble! What service can I use to fetch the content from XML and feed it into IFTTT, so it can be published on my blog. As far as I see, IFTTT only takes RSS as input for this sort of things.

I've tried [pipe2py](https://github.com/ggaughan/pipe2py) to turn the Pipe into Python code (if that would work at all), but I can't get pipe2py working, not on GAE (as I need an online service) and not on my Windows PC either.

I'm experienced with YQL as well, but that only outputs XML, no RSS, so it's of no use here.

So far I can only think of:

1. Implement on GAE/Python my own app that reads XML and turns it into RSS (cumbersome)
2. Manually publish all articles on my blog with a due date (three months of daily articles to go - even more cumbersome)

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you've answered you're own question!

Comment: I don't get it, if you're on wordpress and you need RSS, why don't you just use the one built in from wp? Maybe I didn't understand you correctly...

Answer (score 0):

According to your ideas - you should also consider using WordPress core code to fetch the XML data.

Create a plugin which will load XML data using [HTTP API](https://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) and call proper actions on your blog (in this case IFTTT will be unnecessary for publishing blog posts based on the XML data).

The only issue which you can have is a fact that you will need an access to the server cron - as [wp_cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) by default is called only during the users visits - so on the website with a small traffic it won't work as you can expect (it won't be called as often as you need).